# Dusting Inside All-In-One computer

Tags: cleaning

I have an HP Pavillion 20 with everything inbuilt in the screen and I want to dust the hardware within the screen just like I used to take the side of my old tower and dust inside there.  I have no idea how to do it. Can anyone help

Comment: you have dust inside your screen? are we talking CRT?

Comment: No, I think she's talking about an all in one, and the system board inside it.

Comment: Someone please change "windows-8" tag to "cleaning" or something. I have no permissions on this community yet.

Answer (score 3):

All-In-One systems such as the HP Pavilion 20 are much like laptops for cleaning, as they are designed to be difficult to take apart, and even attempting to do so can void your warranty. There are no user-friendly side-panels to take off, and removing the machine screws will mean HP will not support the machine for hardware failures.

You should still be able to clean it. [HP recommends](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c00326541&tmp_task=useCategory&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=5296650) a small battery-powered vacuum to clean out the cooling vents, which are located on the back of the machine around the perimeter of the screen. As your HP Pavilion is so thin, this should be very successful, as long as there is not a significant buildup and are not in a damp, dusty environment.

Fans should be held steady to prevent damage to them. If the fans are close to the vents, you can hold them steady with a toothpick in one hand while you vacuum with the other.

A can of compressed air could also be used in combination with the vacuum to assist loosening material, but if you do not use it in combination with a small vacuum you run the risk of blowing the dust further inside the machine and clogging it even more.

Comment: +1 I like answers with references (link to HP recommendations).